# Detecting xml:space="preserve" attribute with C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I'm parsing Word docx documents and in the text runs  there are elements similar to the following that occur quite often:

```
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"></w:t>
```

The *run* variable in the line below is an *XElement* and I want to be able to get the attribute value of *xml:space* and I suspect that I need to do something like:

```
var value = run.Attributes(xml + "space")
```

but I'm don't know what the *XNamespace* declaration for *xml* should be. Can someone tell me what the correct namespace declaration is or offer an alternative means of getting the attribute value.

Comment: The namespace whose name is http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace is bound by definition to the prefix xml:. Found @ http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace

Answer (score 1):

With a bit more digging I established that (like codemonkey) that the namespace is indeed http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace but there's no actual  need to import it directly. First ensure that the usings include *System.Xml.Linq*, then declare:

```
XName xml_space = XNamespace.Xml + "space";
```

and then to get the attribute value:

```
string value= "";
var attribute = run.Attributes(xml_space).FirstOrDefault();
if(attribute != null)
    {
    value = attribute.Value;
    }
```